# Advanced GLSL shader runs fine on AMD but crashes on nVidia

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, nvidia, glfw

I am working to an OpenGL graphic engine which can render transparent meshes with accuracy. The full project is available [here](https://github.com/TheBrokenGod/OmegaEngine); it is a Visual Studio 2017 solution (you may need to install the Windows 10 SDK) but also includes a makefile to build under Linux. It uses linked lists of fragments on the GPU which are then sorted and blended back-to-front.

*More specifically this is done with two buffers and an atomic counter: the first buffer holds, for every pixel, a pointer to the head of its list and is atomically updated when rendering meshes; the second buffer holds the actual nodes (a node is fragment's color and pointer to the next node) and the atomic counter is used to reserve a unique position within this second buffer.*

The problem is that everything works fine on my notebook with discrete AMD graphics, but crashes on my other nVidia PC (GT 740, very cheap). **It crashes both on Windows and Linux and both with the official driver and the open source stack**. The code that cause this is inside the sorting shader (please see the TODO comment):

```
int listBegin = listsHeads[getPixelBufferIndex()];

if(listBegin != -1)
{
    // Sort linked list using bubble sort
    bool swapped;
    do
    {
        // Start at list head
        swapped = false;
        int previousNode = listBegin;
        int currentNode = listsNodes[listBegin].nextNode;

        // Loop until list end
        while(currentNode != -1)
        {
            // Furthest first
            float previousDepth = listsNodes[previousNode].depth;
            float currentDepth = listsNodes[currentNode].depth;

            // TODO fix crash on nVidia
            if(previousDepth < currentDepth)
            {
                swapped = true;
                FragmentNode temp;
                temp.color = listsNodes[currentNode].color;
                temp.meshId = listsNodes[currentNode].meshId;

                listsNodes[currentNode].color = listsNodes[previousNode].color;
                listsNodes[currentNode].depth = previousDepth;
                listsNodes[currentNode].meshId = listsNodes[previousNode].meshId;

                listsNodes[previousNode].color = temp.color;
                listsNodes[previousNode].depth = currentDepth;
                listsNodes[previousNode].meshId = temp.meshId;
            }
            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = listsNodes[currentNode].nextNode;                 
        }
    }
    while(swapped);
}
```

If I remove the inner if the program no longer crashes, but of course the result is incorrect since the lists are not sorted. **I am starting to think that there is a problem with my particular graphic card model**, because crashing both with the binary driver and the open source stack on the same card seems to suggests that. But maybe there is actually a bug in the shader that I couldn't find.

Any idea? This is the output I want:

[image: Correct output]

Comment: A blind shot: Replace `FragmentNode temp` with two float vars.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from bubble sort to selection sort solved the issue. No idea however why it was crashing the GPU.